# Testing BTLE App on iOS 8.1 Simulator

Tags: ios, simulator, btle

I am new to iOS app development. I have to test an app using BTLE on iOS 8.1 simulator. I am not able to find how to switch on the bluetooth in the simulator. Could any one please help how to test a BTLE based app on the simualtor. Also it be of great help if anyone can answer if paying $99 is mandatory to deploy my app on my iPHone/iPad usinng my MacBook Air?

Systems Details are:
OS X 10.9.4
Xcode 6.1
iOS 8.1 Simulator
iOS SDK 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth Low Energy is not supported in the simulator.  You need to test on a real device.

To install an application onto a device you will need a paid membership of the Apple developer programme

Comment: Thank you Mr.Paul Wilkinson for the quick response !

Answer (score 1):

Although BLE is not supported in the iOS Simulator, Core Bluetooth **is** supported on newer Macs in OS X apps.  So if you put all the iOS app's Bluetooth code in a a controller or model object separate from the UIKit UI code, you can also use that same BLE code inside an OS X app to test it out.